# How can I right-align a complete Dojo DataGrid?

Tags: css, datagrid, dojo

I am developing an Arabic version of a website. I want to right-align a complete Dojo DataGrid. I found only an option to right-align the columns.

Is there any option to right-align the complete DataGrid (i.e., columns and rows)?

Answer (score 0):

try to add this line in your main css file :

```
.dojoxGridCell {
     text-align: right !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For all languages that go from right to left you should use `<html dir="rtl">` in HTML or

```
html {
  direction:rtl;
}
```

in CSS